# WCF array datacontract

Tags: wcf, serialization

I have a scheme that looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>        
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:element name="RequestResponseBase" type="RequestResponseBase" />
        <xs:complexType name="RequestResponseBase">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Parameters"
                            type="Parameters">
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="Parameters">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0"
                            maxOccurs="unbounded"
                            name="Parameter"
                            type="Parameter">
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="Parameter">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
```

I want to create datacontracts for the types so I've defined the following classes

```
    public class RequestResponseBase
    {
        public Parameters Parameters { get; set; }
    }


    public class Parameters
    {
        public Parameter[] Parameter { get; set; }
    }
```

But when I run the service and create a request with soapUI it suggests me to fill the following request:

```
  <tem:RequestResponseBase>
     <wcf:Parameters>
        <wcf:Parameter>
           <wcf:Parameter>
              <wcf:Name>gero et</wcf:Name>
              <wcf:Value>sonoras imperio</wcf:Value>
           </wcf:Parameter>
        </wcf:Parameter>           
     </wcf:Parameters>
  </tem:RequestResponseBase>
```

Why `Parameter` element is wrapped with another `Parameter` element and how to avoid that?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you change your code to:

```
public class RequestResponseBase
{
    public Parameter[] Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This gives me exactly what I want, but I might want to add some elements to `Parameters` type.

Comment: You can't without adding the extra level.

Comment: Can you pls show me an example of classes I have to create to achieve the result I need?